# Allow copy / paste in a text_area field form but remove formatting

Tags: ruby, forms, sanitize

I have a text_area field in a form which allows some text formatting through a very simple WYSIWYG (bold / underline / bullet points). This was aimed at having a consistent formatting in the description profile of the users.

```
 <%= l.text_area :access, value: "#{t('.access_placeholder_html')}" %>
```

Nevertheless, some users usually filled the text_area by copy / pasting directly from their website. And their specific formatting "hypertext links", font size, etc. is after reflected on my website, which makes it a bit dirty.

How can I solve this problem. Ideally I would love that when saving the form it gets rid of all the HTML code that is not allowed instead of not allowing copy / paste. Is this possible? Was wondering if should use Sanitize but if so how? (Sorry new to code, I guess you would have understood).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of Rails, but you could use `#sanitize` from `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` module to strip all the HTML formatting. It scrubs HTML from text with a scrubber. The default scrubber allows optional whitelisting of attributes. You can even build your own custom scrubber to modify the string if you need more control over what is output. The module also contains `#strip_tags` and `#strip_links`, which are very simple scrubbers that remove all HTML tags and all HTML link tags (leaving the link text).

Note that you can wind up with malformed text if the user's input wasn't valid HTML.

Quick examples from the docs:

```
// remove all HTML tags except <strong> <em> <a> and the 
// <href> attributes from @text
nomarkup_text = sanitize @text, tags: %w(strong em a), attributes: %w(href)

// remove all HTML markup
strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
```

returns the string `Bold no more!  See more here...`

```
// remove just the link markup
strip_links('Please e-mail me at <a href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a>.')
```

returns the string `Please e-mail me at me@email.com.`

More detail at the [API page for SantizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

Comment: One more thing, you can store the HTML markup in the database and sanitize in the view before display. That way, in the future you can do something more with HTML text, if you choose. If you throw the formatting away before storing, it is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply and the link. I am using Ruby 2.2.1. I should have told you I already went through the sanitize documentation before posting. So if I opt for option 2, (get rid of the formatting before storing), how should I write it ?
How can I combine the form field and sanitize together?

Comment: The simplest way would be to sanitize the string in the model when assigning the text_field to the model attribute before saving to the database. You can't really process the form_field on the fly without some careful thought (e.g., what would you do if the unfinished text wasn't well-formed HTML). You could run some javascript when the text_field loses focus and strip out the HTML, but if you put the result back in the text_field it might be confusing to the user. You need to define exactly what you want to do before choosing an implementation method.